# Python Element Tree ParseError

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup, elementtree

Thanks for all your help in advance!

I am working with a large text data set. Each file containing multiple `.xml` files.
One of those files might look like this (a minimum example reproducing the error mentioned below):

```
'\'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>\\n<!DOCTYPE doc SYSTEM "abnml-1.0b.dtd">\\n<doc msize="000002515" md5="748077a08df8db4a6472a52ed7f31b87" sysId="sbknwsarchp1" destination="AW" distId="    " transmission-date="                " >\\n<abnml publisher="ABC" docdate="20000101" product="ABC" seq="101" xml:lang="en-us" >\\n<head>\\n<copyright year="2000" holder="ABC &amp; Company, Inc." ></copyright>\\n<docdata>\\n<abc>\\n<ABC-news news-source="ABC" origin="AA" service-id="CO" >\\n<abc-press/>\\n<abc-urban>0</abc-urban>\\n<abc-mdata brand="AB" temp-perm="P" retention="N" hot="N" original-source="FW" accession-number="11111" page-citation="" display-date="22000101T164800.000Z" >\\n<abc-coding>\\n<abc-industry>\\n<c>I/BAN</c>\\n<c>I/SCR</c>\\n</abc-industry>\\n<abc-sub>\\n<c>N/CMR</c>\\n<c>N/DJI</c>\\n<c>N/DJN</c>\\n<c>N/EWR</c>\\n<c>N/WER</c>\\n<c>N/BON</c>\\n<c>N/ABS</c>\\n<c>N/ABWI</c>\\n<c>N/TPC</c>\\n<c>N/Y2\\x0b</c>\\n</abc-sub>\\n<abc-mark>\\n<c>M/NND</c>\\n</abc-mark>\\n<abc-prod>\\n<c>P/AS03</c>\\n</abc-prod>\\n</abc-cod>\\n</djn-mdata>\\n</abc-news>\\n</abc>\\n</docdata>\\n</head>\\n<body>\\n<headline prefix="="  brand-display="AB" >\\nJames Bond Is OK</headline>\\n<text>\\n<pre>\\n \\n </pre>\\n<p>\\n  NEW --The new year. </p>\\n<p>\\n  &quot;It was as usual (N`w Year&apos;s Eve) night, on Monday,&quot; said the. </p>\\n<p>\\n  at|the agency. </p>\\n<p>\\n  The firm. </p>\\n<p>\\n  In addition Jan. 1, 2200, didn&apos;t recommended early last year &quot;repurchase&quot; fist few days of January. involve wire&#233;&#219; measure.&quot; </p>\\n<p>\\n  And, to be fair, mend&#225;tion: they&apos;ve 2000,  there isn&apos;t a need eur&#227;&#219;&gt;+ </p>\\n<p>\\n  (END) </p>\\n<p>\\n  January 01, 2200 11:48 ET (16:48 GMT)</p>\\n</text>\\n</body>\\n</abnml>\\n</doc>\''
```

My first go to solution for extracting the necessary parts was using Python's standard library `xml.etree.ElementTree`. Please find below a minimum working example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open('EXAMPLE.nml', "rt") as file: 
    contents = file.read()

root = ET.fromstring(contents)
```

When running the snippet on the example text above, the following ERROR is returned:

```
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 28, column 7
```

After extensively browsing through beloved stackoverflow, I have already tried the following alternatives:

- using the `lxml.etree` library, reading in the file as bites (as it allows for the "recover" option):

:

```
from lxml import etree

with open('EXAMPLE.nml', "rb") as file: 
    contents = file.read()

parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
root = etree.fromstring(contents,parser=parser)
```

This solution actually works on this file, however, returns the same error for other files. The overall issue is that the data set is rather massive and complex. The script has to run on a server, and it is impossible to code small workarounds for all individual cases or to test each and every file.

Some comments on other posts suggested "fixing the process that generated the file instead of the .xml file itself". However, given that the data set is externally provided, this is simply not feasible.

- As another possibility I tried decoding and re-encoding the file before parsing, because this seemed to have fixed the issue for other users (though some mentioned that the solution does not seem to work in newer releases). This also did not work for me.
- As a last option I tried using `BeautifulSoup`. I had two issues with this option:

  - using the `lxml` parser left me with an empty parse tree
  - using the standard bs4 parser/or the `html.parser` leads to a parse tree, however, the structure seems to be messed up such that reading out the appropriate children in later steps of my code fails.

I am running the following versions (on a widows machine):

- python (anaconda): 3.8.10
- lxml:  4.6.3
- beautifulsoup4: 4.9.3

Would be grateful for any hints or suggestions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So it looks like your issue is the `\\x0b` which is a vertical tab.  It's not clear if that has any semantic meaning, but I think you may end up needing to clean this XML before parsing.

Comment: @KyleParsons Thanks a lot for your swift reply! Sorry for having to remove a lot of the text (given that it is external, I had to make it basically meaningless). Either way, I was actually thinking of using regular expressions. However, as mentioned in my question the data set is so massive that it is almost impossible to know which tokens might produce errors in other data examples (if not the same). Does any cleaning step come to your mind which is general enough to - hopefully - take care of these issues, yet not too general and potentially destructive? Any comments is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @KyleParsons Quick update: `clean = re.sub('\x0b','', EXAMPLE.decode())` and then `ET.fromstring(clean)` seems to resolve the issue for this specific case at least! However, I am almost certain that other elements might provoke a similar error in other files. Is there a way to read out the troublesome token dynamically to then remove it with `re` in e.g. a `try` `except` statement or something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again thanks for the helpful comments!

After some testing, I found two possible solutions for my problem. Since - to the best of my knowledge - they do not seem to be documented on e.g. SO, I hope they will be useful to others running into similar issues.

- As mentioned before in the question, I also tried using `BeautifulSoup` or `bs4`. The initial problem can be solved by using:

:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import lxml

with open('EXAMPLE.nml', "rb") as file: 
contents = file.read()
    
soup = bs(contents, features="lxml")
```

for this to work, first `lxml` and then `bs4` have to be installed. This should automatically install the `lxml` parser for `bs4`. As mentioned in the original question, the drawback is, that the resulting parse tree has a different structure and later parts of the code have to be adjusted.

- Solution 2: One of the comments pushed me into this direction. Instead of the `bs4` work around, I implemented the following bit of code:

:

```
from lxml import etree
import re 



 try:
        parser = etree.XMLParser(ns_clean=True, recover=True)
        root = etree.fromstring(contents,parser=parser) 
                
 except:
        fixed = re.sub(r"[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\u10000-\u10FFFF]", "", contents.decode()).encode()
        parser = etree.XMLParser(ns_clean=True, recover=True)
        root = etree.fromstring(fixed,parser=parser)
```

This solution has the advantage that the rest of the code does not have to be changed. It actively seems to solve the issue that, even with the `ns_clean=True, recover=True` arguments the `lxml` parser seemed to fail on some files.